# Can I have a pointer on pointer on const in C++?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, constants, extern-c

Basically I am wondering whether something like

```
f(const void* a){
  // This is also what `(char**) a` would do behind the scenes
  char** string_a_ptr {reinterpret_cast<char**>(const_cast<void*>(a))}; 

  // ...
```

is possible while preserving the `const` qualifier.

My question came up during an exercise about C-Arrays in C++. Because of C, I had to pass a function pointer with `const void*` arguments. In this case it was pointing on an array of C-strings. To cast it to the correct type I had to cast the const away. Is there a way in C++ to get something like a "(const char*)*"` pointer?

I have tried out `const char**` (without the const_cast) which yields

> reinterpret_cast from type ‘const void*’ to type ‘const char**’ casts away qualifiers

and `(const*)*`, which gives a syntax error

> expected type-specifier before ‘(’ token

This is a purely academic question. I am aware, that the problem can be solved easier and saver using `std::string` and `#include <algorithm>`.

While I am at it, are there advantages of sometimes using C-constructions in C++ or should they always be avoided if possible? I only did some small scale exercise problems with C code in C++, but it already causes quite a few headaches and forces me to look really closely under the hood, even though I have written a fair amount of C code in my life.
Or is it would you rather recommend using the `extern C` qualifier  and writing C code in pure C?

Comment: `const void*` would be `char* const*`. (It’s more obvious if you position the `const` qualifier consistently: `void const*`.)

Comment: I understand. Rewriting this as `void const*` is exactly what solves my confusion. Thanks!

Comment: "are there advantages of sometimes using C-constructions in C++" Yes. But you should always try to avoid them and know how much the C construct is costing you in readability, type-correctness or maintainability. In case of a `void*`that's all three of them you lose on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be a `char* const *`.

There are three places in a double pointer to put const:

```
const char**
```

Pointer, to a pointer, to a character you cannot change.

```
char *const *
```

pointer, to a pointer you cannot change, to a character.

```
char ** const
```

pointer you cannot change, to a pointer, to a character.

You can mix these to make different parts const.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
const char * const * string_a_ptr = static_cast<const char * const *>(a);
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07810f1b7c66837d)

You could even drop the first `const` if you want (and it makes sense).

Explanation:

`const void * a` means that `a` points to something (`void`) which is `const`. Therefore, if you cast `a` to another pointer, it must also point to something that is `const`. In your case, you're casting it to a pointer to `char*`. That `char*` must therefore be `const`. The syntax for creating a constant pointer (**not** a pointer to a constant) is to put the `const` to the right of the `*`. Hence, `char* const *`.